# Help me find the solution to the IVP in implicit form?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I am having a problem with the **(2)**.Please help me.

> **Text-book Question:**
>
> Consider the IVP:
>
> $$\color{crimson}{(105\sin(3y-15x)-y)dx+(-21\sin(3y-15)-x+2y)dy=0}$$
>
> $$\color{#06f}{y(8)=40}$$

---

(1) Verify that the ODE is exact and Find $u(x,y)$:

$$u(x,y)=7\cos(3y-15x)-yx+y^2$$

---

**(2) Hence find the solution to the IVP, in implicit form:**

Now since this question says Hence, and also my notes say that the solution for a IVP is $u(x,y)=C$, so this should mean that:

$$7\cos(3y-15x)-yx+y^2=C$$

So the only way to find C, is to use $\color{#06f}{y(8)=40}$, so I did that:

$$C=7\cos(0)-40(8)+40^2=1287$$

$$\color{grey}{\text{which makes no sense...}}$$

So I tried this:

$$\color{crimson}{(105\sin(3y-15x)-y)dx+(-21\sin(3y-15)-x+2y)dy=0}$$

$$(105\sin(3y-15x)-y)dx=(21\sin(3y-15)+x-2y)dy$$

$$-y^2+xy-7\cos(3y-15x)=7\cos(15x-3y)-xy$$

$$\color{green}{\text{Which gets me lost...}}$$

**My question: What is the question actually asking me to do?**

Comment: The ODE is _not_ exact. Didn't you make a typo somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a $\color{red}{\mbox{typo}}$, I think, in the first place. The differential equation is an exact one if:
$$
\left[105\sin(3y-15x)-y\right]dx+\left[-21\sin(3y-15\color{red}{x})-x+2y\right]dy=0
$$
So it is supposed that such is the case. When put:
$$
du = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} dy = 0
$$
then we have:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right) =
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right) = 315\cos(3 y - 15 x) - 1
$$
And the original ODE is reproduced with:
$$
u(x,y)=7\cos(3y-15x)-yx+y^2 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \left\{ 
\begin{array}{l} \partial u/\partial x = 105\sin(3 y - 15 x) - y \\
\partial u/\partial y = -21\sin(3 y - 15 x) - x + 2 y \end{array} \right.
$$
We know that $du=0$ , so indeed $u(x,y) = C$ is the solution.
However, $C$ can be anything, not just $C=1287$ ; I don't see either how to make sense of the additional "condition" $y(8)=40$ .